# How to add code into wordpress site?

Tags: html, wordpress

Hello I have just started to use word press today, I have developed my own theme, and edited the header and footer files to show what I want it to show, however I’ve ran into a problem adding in the main content. What I did was just take the html, and dump it into the html editor and this worked great site was fine, however if you click into the visual editor and then click at the start of a div, and press “backspace” it removes the div and merges it with the div above it, should this happen? And if that is what is supposed to happen can you prevent it?.

Allot of my potential clients don’t want a html website and want word press and that makes me lose them since I am mainly html/css/php etc, so that’s why I'm learning it, however if the above is what happens it seems like these clients will keep on coming back to me wanting it fixed etc and make me look bad for making sites that break easily thus decreasing my value as a freelancer.

Any and all help is welcome the reason I'm asking is because i can’t find any websites about this they are all purely make a theme. Thank you.

P.S this site is running locally so cannot provide link sorry.

Comment: I believe your looking at this wrong.  You want to use Wordpress for your clients so you DON'T have to add html in a page or post.

The specific problem your having is due to Wordpress updating the content through the WYSIWYG.

You really want to try and build a wordpress theme that will function with just basic html.  Heading, paragraph, etc, that is available in the WYSIWYG.  Keep it simple.  Building a site that allows clients (with little html experience) to edit their own content, means making it very simple to use.

Comment: Yes what you say makes sense, I'm trying to make something like your main div at the top, with 3 smaller one's below floated to the left to form a horizontal line with another big one below, again this is fine using html, i will need to work on it more, it's only been 5 or so hours so didn't expect it to be easy haha thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't rely on `visual editor` for comples `html` layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with @jhanifen, your client will not want to post html into the WYSIWYG editor, so keep in mind your theme will have to allow what ever they choose to put in there.

You wont be able to prevent the behaviour you are describing, you could lock the page from other users editing it but this is a bad way to go.

I usually make a child theme of a good simple standard theme and create page templates to allow for different page styling. http://codex.wordpress.org/Page_Templates

You may also want to look into custom post formats for more specific posting behaviour. http://webdesignledger.com/tips/getting-started-with-wordpress-post-formats.

Comment: Thank you for the reply i will look into what you have linked me to. Thanks again